# Creating directories from Windows to WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to create user-privilleged directories from Windows to WSL directly?

I can create a folder from Windows, but it won't be the same as `mkdir` in WSL. For example, using Windows Explorer I create a new folder `A`

[image]

But, coming back to WSL, I can't cd `A`:

```
-bash: cd: A: Permission denied
```

Unless I do `chmod 0761 *` eventually. Isn't there a way to do that automatically?

Comment: No. This is by-design. It is not recommended to create/remove WSL file/folder from Windows.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to create/mimic the directory with Windows API e.g. NtSetEaFile().